# Overwrite setOnMarkerDragListener dont move marker

Tags: android, google-maps, overwrite

Sorry about my English.
On Google Map Android API marker doesn't have Longclick event. So i use setOnMarkerDragListener to catch the Longclick event. But unfortunately the marker still move on the map. I've tried to overwrite but seem not work. Here is my code:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {
        LatLng temp = null;
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            temp=marker.getPosition();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            marker.setPosition(temp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //LatLng temp = marker.getPosition();
            marker.setPosition(temp);
        }
    });
```

The marker still move on the map. All i want is marker stay in position. Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

overriding the onMarkerDragListener does not stop it from being moved, there is no long click listener for a marker, you cannot do what you want to do.

you need to rethink your approach to what you need to accomplish.

the only thing you can do is override `onMapLongClick` and then loop through all your markers and see if you pressed on one or are close to one but that brings up other issues too